# Rank within group in for loop in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rank

I am very close to a solution for a ranking exercise within a group of a panel dataframe (aware of similar questions surrounding this problem, for example: [Specific group rankings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692427/specific-group-rankings-in-r)).

```
Category    ID          Score.08.2007   Score.09.2007    Rank.08.2007    Rank.09.2007   ...
Orange      FSGBR070N3  0.16            ...              5               ...
Orange      FSGBR070N3  0.05            ...              7               ...
Orange      FSGBR070N3  0.11                             6
Orange      FS00008L4G  0.28                             1
Orange      FS00008VLD  0.27                             2
Orange      FS00008VLD  0.27                             3
Orange      FS00008VLD  0.27                             4
Orange      FS00009SQX  -2.03                            8
Orange      FS00009SQX  NA                          
Orange      FSUSA0A1KW  NA          
Orange      FSUSA0A1KW  NA  
Orange      FSUSA0A1KX  NA  
Orange      FSUSA0A1KY  NA  
Orange      FS0000B389  NA  
Banana      FS000092GP  96.25                            1
Banana      FS000092GP  96.25                            2
Banana      FS000092GP  96.25                            3
Banana      FS000092GP  52.33                            4
Banana      FS0000ATLN  31.73                            5
Banana      FSUSA0AVMF  1.38                             7
Banana      FSGBR058O8  1.37                             8
Banana      FSGBR05845  2.24                             6
```

code:

```
for (i in 4:ncol(MRAR)){
  eq_ranks[i] <- lapply(unique(MRAR$Morningstar.Category),function(x)
    {
     a <- rank(MRAR[MRAR$Morningstar.Category == x, i], na.last="keep")
     return(a)
  })
}
```

.error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(c(NA, 1047, NA, NA,  : 
replacement element 1 has 3159 rows, need 3530
```

I have seen ave approaches as well, but ave syntax does not seem to permit the na.last="keep" requirement. But I also developed a dplyr approach:

```
aux <- as.vector(cbind(names(ER)))

eq_ranks <- function(MRAR,group_by){
  group_by %>%
    group_by(!!Morningstar.Category) %>% 
mutate_at(MRAR,quo(eq_rank=rank(MRAR)), vars(aux))
}
```

again, this treats NA values as "last" (not as "keep"), semantic logic seems correct though.

Really appreciate your help, 
Wilhelm Fantastisch.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to rank `NA` values as well?

Comment: Hi Chi, thanks for the reply. No, I want to explicitly exclude NA values from the ranking, i.e. keep them as in the data (na.last="keep".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you wanted but with the `data.frame` below this worked for me. Hope it helps

```
df <- data.frame(Category=c(rep("Orange",10), rep("Banana",10)),
             Score.08.2007=c(runif(6),rep(NA,4),runif(4),rep(NA,2),runif(4)),
             Score.09.2017=c(runif(5),rep(NA,3),runif(2),runif(4),rep(NA,4),runif(2)),
             stringsAsFactors=F)
```

#### dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)

eq_ranks <- function(theseCols, newCols, df){
               theseCols <- enquo(theseCols)
               df1 <- df %>%
                       group_by(Category) %>%
                       mutate_at(vars(!!theseCols), funs(rank(., na.last="keep"))) %>%
                       ungroup() %>%
                       select(-Category) %>%
                       setNames(newCols)
               df2 <- cbind(df, df1)
               return(df2)
            }

aux <- colnames(df)[-1]
newCols <- sub("Score", "Rank", aux)
eq_ranks(aux,newCols,df)
```

#### Output

```
structure(list(Category = c("Orange", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange", 
"Orange", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange", "Banana", 
"Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", 
"Banana", "Banana"), Score.08.2007 = c(0.757087148027495, 0.202692255144939, 

0.711121222469956, 0.121691921027377, 0.245488513959572, 0.14330437942408, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.239629415096715, 0.0589343772735447, 0.642288258532062, 
0.876269212691113, NA, NA, 0.778914677444845, 0.79730882588774, 
0.455274453619495, 0.410084082046524), Score.09.2017 = c(0.810870242770761, 
0.604933290276676, 0.654723928077146, 0.353197271935642, 0.270260145887733, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.99268406117335, 0.633493264438584, 0.213208135217428, 
0.129372348077595, 0.478118034312502, 0.924074469832703, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.59876096714288, 0.976170694921166), Rank.08.2007 = c(6, 
3, 5, 1, 4, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, 5, 8, NA, NA, 6, 7, 4, 3
), Rank.09.2017 = c(6, 3, 5, 2, 1, NA, NA, NA, 7, 4, 2, 1, 3, 
5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 6)), .Names = c("Category", "Score.08.2007", 
"Score.09.2017", "Rank.08.2007", "Rank.09.2017"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hey @Chi Pak, thank you! I'd have two final issues on this; there are some decimal values, can I require integers only somewhere? Finally, can you help me getting this as.data.frame output? I know this should be straight forward.. It creates values for aux and newCols and the eq_ranks function... Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your first question. Do you mean specify only columns with integer values? Try `aux <- colnames(df)[-1][is.integer(colnames(df)[-1])]`...To save `eq_ranks(aux,newCols,df)` to variable, `newname <- eq_ranks(aux,newCols,df)`